# WiX Custom Action not setting ACL

Tags: wix, acl, custom-action

I have a C# custom action running in WiX:

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult SetAppDataSecurity(Session session)
    {
        session.Log("Running security...");
        session.Log("Creating dInfo...");
        // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "MyApp");

        session.Log("dInfo.FullName is " + dInfo.FullName);
        session.Log("dInfo.Exists is " + dInfo.Exists);

        session.Log("Creating dSecurity...");
        // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the current security settings.
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
        session.Log("dSecurity ACL count is " + dSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, Type.GetType("System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier")).Count);

        session.Log("dSecurity.AddAccessRule...");
        // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Authenticated Users", FileSystemRights.Write, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));

        session.Log("dInfo.SetAccessControl...");
        // Set the new access settings.
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
        session.Log("dSecurity ACL count is " + dSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, Type.GetType("System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier")).Count);
        session.Log("SetAppDataSecurity done.");
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

It is being called by my installer on another machine - this is the msiexec log:

```
Action ended 23:24:56: InstallFinalize. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (78:F0) [23:24:56:518]: Doing action: SetAppDataSecurity
MSI (s) (78:F0) [23:24:56:518]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 23:24:56: SetAppDataSecurity. 
Action start 23:24:56: SetAppDataSecurity.
MSI (s) (78:70) [23:24:56:612]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSICC37.tmp, Entrypoint: SetAppDataSecurity
SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\Users\EDIT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\abcdef.tmp-\ //edited
SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v4.0.30319
Calling custom action WiXCustomActions!WiXCustomActions.CustomActions.SetAppDataSecurity
Running security...
Creating dInfo...
dInfo.FullName is C:\ProgramData\MyApp
dInfo.Exists is True
Creating dSecurity...
dSecurity ACL count is 6
dSecurity.AddAccessRule...
dInfo.SetAccessControl...
dSecurity ACL count is 7
SetAppDataSecurity done.
Action ended 23:24:57: SetAppDataSecurity. Return value 1.
Action ended 23:24:57: INSTALL. Return value 1.
```

When I look at the folder it's security has not been set with the "Authenticated Users".

This same code was being used in a previous Setup and Deployment project and worked fine and added the Authenticated Users group with write permissions.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the permission or permissionex elements directly in WIX? http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_permission.htm

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Didn't think about that as I was migrating code. Still curious why the CA doesn't work though.